# CALayers does not appears on real device

Tags: ios-simulator, ios7, calayer

I have some problems with CALayers. I have UITableView with custom TableViewCells, in this cells i draw some objects using CALayers. When I run my app on IOS 7 simulator, it works great. But when i run app on real IPhone 5 - no layers are appears. Help solve this problem plz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue and resolved it by modifying the property attributes of my CALayer. I was using (weak, nonatomic) and a change to (strong, nonatomic) caused them to appear on the device.